# Presenting ViewController on Tabbar Item

Tags: swift

I have a tabbar with 3 items. When I click on the second Item on the Tab, I want to present another tabbar which would be like a presentation and maybe the rootViewcontroller but I am unable to do that because it appears like a normal controller above the main tabbar.

I have extended `UITabBarControllerDelegate`

```
override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
        if let controller = self.viewControllers?[self.selectedIndex] as? BaseVC {

           controller.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
           self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

`BaseVC` is the Tabbar controller I am trying to present.

but this does not change the behavior of the item.

Comment: you need to present tab bar controller ... instead on viewController

Comment: BaseVC is a subclass of Tabbar controller

Comment: is it presenting anything ?

Comment: It shows all the view controllers in the tabbar.

Comment: all the controllers .... please elaborate

Comment: `BaseVC` is a tabbar controller I am trying to present over the current Tabbar when I click on the second item